# Cómo configurar una template descargada en mi app ionic

Tags: ionic3

soy un novato en el tema de las APP.

me he descargado una template de ionic [https://market.ionicframework.com/starters/ionic-tabs-starter-templates-3]

Tras seguir las instrucciones de instalación de ionic de la web oficial, me gustaría insertar la template que me descargué en la app que me acabo de crear con `ionic start`.

según he visto por internet, me pone que tengo que insertarla en la carpeta ***www*** pero no me crea esa carpeta, me crea la carpeta ***src***

Alguien me podría decir los pasos a seguir para insertar esta template en la APP o si esta template ya tiene todo lo necesario para funcionar, cómio configurar dicha template para que me arranque con el `ionic serve`?

Comment: puedes agregar el comando exacto con el cual creaste la app talvez "ionic start test001 blank"???. Por qué el template que te muestra es solamente la unión de 2 templates tabs y sidemenu

Comment: he creado varias a ver si podía enlazar la template con alguna. he creado las 3 opciones que me ponía `ionic start myApp1 blank`, otra `ionic start myApp2 tabs` y la del menú `ionic start myApp3 sidemenu` pero no he conseguido enlazar la template con ninguna

Comment: te dejo en la respuesta todos los cambios que hice para realizar la implementación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El presente es realizado tomando en cuenta que se trabajo sobre el template tabs y s e le agrego el sidemenu.
Lo primero a realizar es la creación de las pages a las cuales va a acceder el sidemenu por lo tanto se agregue 2 paginas extras

```
ionic g page test1
ionic g page test2
```

dentro de tu src/pages se generan las 2 pages con sus css, ts, etc y en sus respectivas carpetas.

posteriormente vamos a modificar el src/app/app.html con lo siguiente:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>
          Menu
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button ion-item menuClose (click)="openHome()">
        <ion-icon name="ios-home-outline"></ion-icon>
        Home
      </button>
      <button ion-item menuClose (click)="openTest1()">
        <ion-icon name="ios-list-box-outline"></ion-icon>
        TEST001
      </button>
      <button ion-item menuClose (click)="openTest2()">
        <ion-icon name="ios-list-box-outline"></ion-icon>
        TEST002
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" #content [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

Con esto podemos notar que existen unas funciones para ingresar a sus respectivas páginas. Para esto vamos agregarlas en el archivo src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';


import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { test1 } from '../pages/test1/test1'
import { test2 } from '../pages/test2/test2'

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage:any = TabsPage;

  constructor(platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();      

    });
  }

  openTest1(){
    this.nav.setRoot(test1)
  }

  openTest2(){
    this.nav.setRoot(test2)
  }

  openHome(){
    this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage)
  }


}
```

Podemos notar que se agregaron ViewChild de @angular-core y Nav de ionic-angular.

Ahora bien tambien necesitamos registrar las pages en app.module.ts

```
import { test1 } from '../pages/test1/test1';
import { test2 } from '../pages/test2/test2';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
```

y tambien los agregamos en @NgModule en declarations:

```
declarations: [
    test1,
    test2,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,    
  ]
```

y en entryComponents:

```
entryComponents: [
    test1,
    test2,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage, 
  ]
```

Con todo esto deberia funcionar correctamente.

Todo esto fue tomado del siguiente [tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-side-menu-tabs/) se encuentra en ingles y realize las modificaciones que yo necesitaba.

Dentro de cada page visible debemos agregar el siguiente codigo, por ejemplo para test1.html sería el siguiente:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Test1</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Donde menuToggle es el encargado de desplegar el sidemenu aunque este funciona deslizando de izquierda a derecha dentro del app.

Comment: gracias, me sirvió bastante el tutorial que pusiste